# current_predicate in SICStus Prolog

Tags: prolog, iso-prolog, sicstus-prolog

SICStus Prolog offers both current_predicate/1 and current_predicate/2.

The [manual page](https://sicstus.sics.se/sicstus/docs/latest4/html/sicstus.html/mpg_002dref_002dcurrent_005fpredicate.html#index-current_005fpredicate_002f_005b1_002c2_005d-_0028built_002din_002c-ref-page_0029-1) states:

> current_predicate(?PredSpec)
>
> Unifies PredSpec with a predicate specifications of the form Name/Arity.
>
> current_predicate(?Name, ?Term)
>
> Unifies Name with the name of a user-defined predicate, and Term with the most general term corresponding to that predicate.

They appear to have the same features:
both predicates work for enumerating predicates, both work with modules.

The manual page comments:

> current_predicate/1 is part of the ISO Prolog standard; current_predicate/2 is not.

Should I ever use `current_predicate/2` in new (= non-legacy) code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer, no. Don't use it in new code.

The benefit of `current_predicate/2` was to allow querying, using a predicate call *template*, if the predicate is defined, unlike `current_predicate/1`. E.g.

```
...,
(   current_predicate(_, foo(_, _)) ->
    foo(A, B)
;   ...
),
...
```

But you can often use instead the standard `predicate_property/2` predicate, which takes a template as first argument.

P.S. The Logtalk linter will scream at you (and suggest a more standard alternative) if it finds you calling `current_predicate/2` :-)